# TextFieldのラッパーを作りたいのですが、関数の渡し方が分かりません

Tags: swift, swift5, swiftui

タイトルの通りです。以下のソースの場合、MyTextFieldのonCommitにMyTextField_PreviewsのOnCommit関数を渡したいのですが、エラーとなってしまいます。
他のstructやclassに処理を渡す方法を教えて下さい。

```
struct MyTextField: View {
    let title = ""
    @State var text: String = ""
    let onCommit: () -> Void

    var body: some View {
        TextField(title, text: $text, onCommit: onCommit)
    }
}

struct MyTextField_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        return VStack {
            MyTextField(onCommit: OnCommit)
        }
    }

    func OnCommit(){

    }
}
```

Comment: 何をしたいかによりますが、ひとまず直接のコンパイルエラーを解決するだけなら、staticメソッドからインスタンスメソッドのOnCommitを使おうとしてインスタンスがないためにエラーになっているので、`MyTextField_Previews`の`OnCommit()`にstaticをつけてstaticメソッドにする（例: `static func OnCommit()``）、
またはインスタンスを作ってOnCommitを参照して渡す（`MyTextField(onCommit: MyTextField_Previews().OnCommit)`のように書く）のどちらかでとりあえずエラーは解消します。
Previewだけの問題なのでそれでもいい気もしますが。。。

Comment: ありがとう御座います！コンパイルエラー解決しました。